# Include PHP file's JS, Css

Tags: php, javascript, css, include

I am trying to include a PHP file in another directory.

Here is my file structure

```
settings\
    manage.php

website \
    index.php
    main.js
    main.css
```

For manage.php

```
echo 'Welcome to the manager! Here is your website:';
include('../website/index.php');
```

index.php

```
 <script src='main.js'></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
```

So, when I load manage.php, I do not get main.js or main.css. How can I get this to work? Maybe include is not the right way to go? I cannot modify anything in the website folder.

[I know iFraming is a possible solution but I'm hoping to get another answer]

Comment: Its usually best to use absolute urls vs relative urls.

Comment: The contents of the website folder are, from the user, I don't know what is going to be in there

Comment: I think framing is the best solution as you seem to be including a complete page / site in your `manage.php` file. That will probably lead to non-valid html (multiple `html`, `body` tags, etc.) and  user styles overwriting yours (or the other way around) that will mess up your design anyway, even if you manage to include the correct assets.

Comment: yes, your manage.php real environment looks like `frames` are what they need and I think they're in quite rare cases. go for them. nobody will put third party html codes in their admin panel documents directly.

Comment: @DachiN. Even worse, php code. I did not even touch the security implications in my previous comment...

Comment: I have only defined one PHP function in manage.php. The goal was to provide this function without having the web developer write `include('manage.php')` in all his files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment below the question: If you want to include some functions / code for your users (instead of the other way around; you including user's stuff in your code), you should look into the [`auto_prepend_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) directive.

Basically, you specify in your php.ini file that you want to prepend (as a `require`) a certain php file before the main file.

**Edit:** As you don't have access to php.ini but you can use a `.htaccess` file, you can put this in your `.htaccess`:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "/path/to/your/file.php"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't have access to php.ini

Comment: @AA You can set these values in an `.htaccess` file as well, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks, I was wasting my time trying to make my own approach, ha ha. Thanks I got it working.

Answer (score 3):

Since you cannot edit `/website/` content you should could try this ugly code for a startup.

Add following just before `include` statement in your manage.php

```
echo('<base href="../website/">');
```

If it works for you, then you can think of sending a correct header with PHP before including a html file, instead of directly echoing a base tag.

**Please consider comments of *jeroen* as down-to-earth solution and use frames**

Comment: +1 A cleaner solution would probably be via an `.htaccess` file if the OP has access to do that.

Comment: yes, and if not he can use `ob_*` methods to get whole `/website/index.php` via include (NOT OUTPUT) and then use `Regexp` to put `<base href=..` code in an appropriate place and then output all.

Comment: True, but as I just commented below the question, it would seem framing is probably the way to go (depending on the exact scenario).

Comment: I have access to htaccess! This solution works well. What would be the htaccess solution?

Comment: Also, arent iFrames slow compared to this solution?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that when the browser loads `/settings/manage.php` it will make requests for `/settings/main.js` and `/settings/main.css` which don't exist

You probably need to change your html in index.php to something like this:

```
<script src="/website/main.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/website/main.css">
```

Note I've made some assumptions about your URLs based on your directory layout so you may need to adjust my solution to make it work for you

Comment: he has no access to `website/` directory